# HTML5, stretch 100% an image until its original size

Tags: css, html

on my site, users can post articles and images, for example:

> blabla [image] bla bla

those articles are surrounded by a div, and inside this div, all img element is set 100% widthed:

```
<div id="articles">
blabla <img src="/image.png" /> bla bla
<hr>
blabla <img src="/image.png" /> bla bla
</div>

#articles img
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

My aim is to make it responsive: if you're browsing on smartphone, fixed dimensioned images wont spoil the design, sadly I cant use "max-width" since I dont know the sizes. I can't ask users to upload images and setting width, height attributes at the same time. Is there a good solution?

Comment: What's wrong with `max-width: 100%`

Comment: The images cant be bigger than its original dimensions. Just imagine how it would look alike on desktop

Comment: So...what's wrong with `max-width: 100%`

Comment: ok, here is an example: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/flexible-images/ first picture. The image wont grow bigger than its original size, but shrinks if theres no place. Thats what I want to achieve.

Comment: In your example, under the heading **"How to create flexible images"** you will find the following CSS: `img { max-width: 100% }`

Comment: Have You read "an example"?

Comment: OOOPS yes yes. I added an unnecessary "width: 100%;" so that "max-width" didnt work. But I removed, and it works OK. Lame question :)

Answer (score 4):

You want to specify a `max-width`:

```
#articles img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This means that an image will never be more than `100%` of it's original size.

***[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgeY2/)***

Answer (score -1):

edit a div to be a max 100% and not the image:

```
<div id="articles">
blabla <div id="image"><?php echo $image ?></div> bla bla
</div>

    #image
    {
    max-width: 100%;
    }
    #articles img {
    width: auto;
    }
```